# Sometimes cannot add post time when posting on my timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Sometimes when using Facebook I've noticed it seems that, if I make too many posts within one day, when I go to make a new post I do not have the option to add a time to the post, just text, pictures, location, and tag faces in pictures. Even once the post is posted to my timeline, and click on the post settings for the post, I still do not have the option to set the date.

This does not happen all the time though, just once in a while. Perhaps it's the Facebook folks doing some maintenance on the database and user interfaces and updates to the underlying Facebook software may be applied incrementally and gradually, so it takes a while for everyone to see them.

That is, after making a few posts to my Facebook timeline, Facebook assumes the date is `NOW`, and does not let me set the date for the post until I have posted the post and some time expires.

Is there a way to circumvent this behavior?